# SQL query advice (replacing exists with joins)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, exists

I have table with following fields and indexes: [image]
I need to make a query that will do:

> check table, if there are **Dial** events, after which (with same
>   unique_id) no **Bridge** or **Hangup** events comes

*or*

> if there are **NewCallerId** events, with no **Hangup** events after it (with same unique_id) or no **Dial** events (with call_id = current unique_id)

There was one query, but I didn't make it work, and users answers didn't help either.
Here's the query that does the work in 395 seconds (too long):

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM   ASTERISK t1 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT t2.* 
               FROM   ASTERISK t2 
               WHERE  t1.OPERATOR_DIAL = '$extension' 
                      AND t1.EVENT = 'Dial' 
                      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT t3.* 
                                      FROM   ASTERISK t3 
                                      WHERE  t3.UNIQUE_ID = t1.UNIQUE_ID 
                                             AND ( t3.EVENT = 'Hangup' 
                                                    OR t3.EVENT = 'Bridge' ))) 
        OR EXISTS (SELECT t4.* 
                   FROM   ASTERISK t4 
                   WHERE  t1.EVENT = 'NewCallerid' 
                          AND t1.OPERATOR_DIAL = '$extension' 
                          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT t5.* 
                                          FROM   ASTERISK t5 
                                          WHERE  ( t5.UNIQUE_ID = t1.UNIQUE_ID 
                                                   AND t5.EVENT = 'Hangup' ) 
                                                  OR ( t5.CALL_ID = t1.UNIQUE_ID 
                                                       AND t5.EVENT = 'Dial' ))) 
ORDER  BY DATE DESC 
LIMIT  1
```

Tried to rewrite it with JOINS, but getting *#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias*

This is my attempt with a JOIN query:

```
SELECT t1.*
                    FROM asterisk t1
                    INNER JOIN (SELECT t2.* FROM asterisk t2
                                  WHERE
                                    t1.operator_dial = '$extension'
                                  AND t1.event = 'Dial'
                                  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT t3.* FROM asterisk t3
                                                  WHERE t3.unique_id = t1.unique_id AND (t3.event = 'Hangup' OR t3.event = 'Bridge')))
                          OUTER JOIN (SELECT t4.* FROM asterisk t4
                                    WHERE t1.event = 'NewCallerid'
                                    AND t1.operator_dial = '$extension'
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT t5.* FROM asterisk t5
                                                    WHERE (t5.unique_id = t1.unique_id AND t5.event = 'Hangup') OR (t5.call_id = t1.unique_id AND t5.event = 'Dial')))
                    ORDER BY DATE DESC
                    LIMIT 1
```

To show, how the query should work I made 2 screenshots (top part has some calls that will not be in query result and bottom part is one call that must be in query result: [image: screen]

Comment: Can you post the JOIN query you tried?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sut22jx5

Answer (score 1):

I have just start posting here on stack exchange. Without diving to deeply I noticed that the inner Joins for t2 and t4 do not have values that match up to any values in t1 (could be why the original query was so long).

old query removed.......

Thanks for the screenshot, that helps. So what you want your query to return are active calls (calls that do not have 'hang-ups' or 'Bridges')Then you want NewcallerID events that do not have an associated dial event and Finally dial events with a bridge before them but no bridge after them

```
SELECT * 
FROM Asterisk t1
WHERE t1.unique_id not in 
    (Select unique_id 
       from Asterisk t2
        Where event = 'Hangup', 'Bridge')
UNION
select *
from asterisk t3
Where event = 'NewCallerID'
    and t3.unique_id not in
      (Select unique_id 
       from Asterisk t4
        Where event = 'Dial')
UNION
Select distinct *
from asterisk t5
    inner join asterisk t6
        on t5.unique_ID = t6.Unique_id
            and t6.event = 'Dial'
Where t5.event = 'Bridge'
         and t6.id > t5.id
```

I think I have covered all the cases here. (Smells a bit hackish though).
Edit: event where a bridge exists before AND After Dial not covered

Comment: It looks like it does not returning any results in my table. I added explanation screenshot up there, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

I THINK you over-complicated it.  By existing to the t2 alias with no join 
on the unique ID, you are getting a Cartesian result.

I've inline commented the query so be sure to take those out before running.

```
SELECT 
      t1.*
   FROM   
      ASTERISK t1
         LEFT JOIN ASTERISK t2 
            ON t1.Unique_ID = t2.Unique_ID
            AND ( t2.Event = 'Hangup' 
               OR t2.Event = 'Bridge' )

         LEFT JOIN ASTERISK t3
            ON t1.unique_id = t3.unique_id
            AND t3.EVENT = 'Hangup'

         LEFT JOIN ASTERISK t4
            ON t1.unique_id = t4.call_id
            AND t4.EVENT = 'Dial'
   WHERE
      -- THESE ARE THE PRIMARY CONDITIONS YOU WANT...
      -- a specific operator extension and looking for
      -- either a dial or newcallerid
          t1.OPERATOR_DIAL = '$extension' 
      AND (    t1.EVENT = 'Dial' 
            OR t1.EVENT = 'NewCallerID' ) 

      AND (   
              -- if an outgoing DIAL, you are concerned with 
              -- alias t2 and NOT having any hangup or bridge
              (    t1.EVENT = 'Dial' 
               AND t2.Unique_ID IS NULL )
           OR 
              -- its from the NewCallerID record via t1 alias
              -- and you do not want hangup or dial based on 
              -- the unique ID vs Call ID respectively to the
              -- t3 and t4 aliases
              (    t1.EVENT = 'NewCallerID'
               AND t3.Unique_ID IS NULL
               AND t4.Unique_ID IS NULL )
          )
  ORDER BY 
     t1.`DATE` DESC 
  LIMIT  1
```

REVISION based on sample data with exception to NewCallerID sample data...

This should extremely simplify what you have -- at least for the outbound calling.  No data showing "NewCallerID", so I can't apply answer for that without better sample data.

Anyhow, I changed to prequery all calls for a given operator extension and have the first and last event based on the apparent auto-increment ID column from the call data record grouped by the unique ID of each call.  From that, its a direct join back to each table so we can see how the call started and the last activity of it.  From there, its a simple where clause that the last event is still in a "newstate" setting.  If there are other settings like an on-hold, conference call, whatever, then this would need to be adjusted to a NOT ( hangup or bridge ) condition...

```
SELECT
      PerCallSummary.*,
      StartCall.event as BeginEvent,
      StartCall.id as BeginEventID,
      LastCall.event as EndEvent,
      LastCall.id as EndEventID
   from
      ( SELECT 
              t1.unique_id, 
              t1.id beginCall, 
              MAX(t2.id) as lastActivity
           from 
              asterisk t1
                 join asterisk t2
                   on t1.unique_id = t2.unique_id
           where 
                 t1.operator_dial = '$extension'
             and t1.event = 'Dial'
           group by
              t1.unique_id,
              t1.id ) as PerCallSummary
      JOIN Asterisk as StartCall
         ON PerCallSummary.beginCall = StartCall.id
      JOIN Asterisk as LastCall
         ON PerCallSummary.lastActivity = LastCall.id
   where
      LastCall.Event = 'Newstate'
```

**ADJUSTMENT TO INNER "PerCallSummary" query**

I think this will fix it...  The reason you didn't get results was me falsely interpreting your data as just being brief of it's content since the operator_dial value was NOT carried forward to every record.  So, the inner query is now adjusted to join to asterisk AGAIN but only on the unique_id of the call (since operator dial would fail otherwise being they were not filled in).  So, the call will always BEGIN with the first t1 record, so I just kept that as basis, but now have just the MAX() of the t2 record ID... Now, you should get correct results to continue this operation.

Anyhow, get some sample data with what a "NewCallerID" looks like and we can tweak this to include that and it's closing criteria.

Comment: It looks like it does not returning any results in my table. I added explanation screenshot up there, please check it.

Comment: @user2682945, revised answer, and need sample of 'NewCallerID' types of calls.

Comment: "NewCallerID" has other unique_id than call itself, and it always has "Dial" after it, so we can forget about "NewCallerID" I think.

Comment: @user2682945, revised answer and think I understand why and explained in answer.